# good books for learning network and web security?

Tags: cryptography, network

I am reading "Hacking The Art of Exploitation" book . i have read till chapter 2 programming but most of it has gone above my head . I want to learn basically cryptography , network security and web security . Which book should i read or should i just skip the first four chapters and go to the chapter 4 network security ?

I know that i am a noob in this field but i am eager to learn and prefer to learn it without joining any course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cryptography basics** 
Coursera.org offers a great course on cryptography. You can check it here: https://www.coursera.org/course/cryptography 
Not only you will be able to learn a lot, Coursera will also help you to test your learning by giving you some tests.

**Web Security/Network Security Basics**
Coming down some books, there is one good book called **Gray Hat Hacking, The Ethical Hackers Handbook, 3rd Edition by Allen Harper**. This book is recommended for newbies and is easily available in almost every bookstore.

Another book on web security is **Web Application Security, A Beginner's - by Bryan Sullivan**

However, I will not suggest you to buy and start reading these books without any prior knowledge. You must first work on improving your programming skills, learning C/C++. PHP, Python, Java and Ruby will help you a lot, and networking skills, basic knowledge of TCP/IP will help you a lot.

You might also want to learn ASM (Assembly language) for developing exploits and reverse engineering.

There is a website called http://opensecuritytraining.info/, which provides free tutorial on various aspects of the information security. You can try that also.

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion.

Comment: Is hacking the art of exploitation book good or bad . Should i read the book as i have read first 2 chapters